# Replace huge amount of string data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table which contains a `NVARCHAR(N)` column with URLs. Unfortunatelly the URLs are absolute. A domain has changed and now links are broken (404). This table is really huge (milions of records). I want to replace the domain or try to make the links relative to fix this issue. How to do it as fast as it is possible with no lock on the table?

**[EDIT]**

I have also tried `UPDATE` and it works only a little bit longer than `INSERT INTO/RENAME`.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

UPDATE [TBL] 
SET [TBL].[Url] = REPLACE([TBL].[Url], 'str1', 'str2')
FROM [MyTable] [TBL] WITH(NOLOCK)
```

It could be done in this way during server maintenance :) Thanks for help!

Comment: also consider splitting the url into multiple columns.

Comment: Its worth noting that the sql you have written will take shared locks. so the nolock is pointless also is the uncommitted isolation level :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new table with the replacement result.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SELECT [TBL].[OTHERCOLUMNS], REPLACE([TBL].[URL],'foo.com','bar.org')
INTO ReplacementTBL
FROM [SOURCETBL] [TBL]

GO
SP_RENAME 'schema.SOURCETBL', SOURCETBL_OLD
GO
SP_RENAME 'schema.ReplacementTBL', SOURCETBL
```

done